# Link notification to a particular post

Tags: android, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using FCM for sending Push Notifications in my application. Push notifications are delivered perfectly, moreover i want that whenever a user clicks on a particular notification,**(Requirement-1)** i can pick the heading of the notification from there and send it to the activity(which i need to open on the push notification click), for which i am using this code inside my FirebaseMessagingService class:

```
private void handleNotification(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    String notTitle = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
    String notBody = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();

    Intent resultIntentMainArticle = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
    resultIntentMainArticle.putExtra("pushNotificationClick", "yes");
    resultIntentMainArticle.putExtra("heading", ""+notTitle);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, resultIntentMainArticle, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.icon_not);
    mBuilder.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
    mBuilder.setContentTitle(notTitle)
            .setContentText(notBody)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
        NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, "NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_NAME", importance);
        notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
        assert mNotificationManager != null;
        mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.icon_not);
        mBuilder.setChannelId(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
        mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
    }
    assert mNotificationManager != null;
    mNotificationManager.notify((int) System.currentTimeMillis() /* Request Code */, mBuilder.build());
}
```

And once the requested activity has been opened,**(Requirement-2)** i need to use that heading to match with the posts in the viewpager used in the activity, and show the post with same heading on the viewpager by setting the viewpager item.

But the problem is, once user have got multiple notifications before clicking on any one, and then he clicks on the notification he recieved first, inside the activity i am not getting the exact heading of which notification has been clicked, its always passing the heading of the recent notification.

I am not sure where i am doing wrong or if i can use some other approach to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by [Tidder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11514525/tidder) in the answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57051587/6429885), which was the answer of **(Requirement-1)**, i was using the same ID inside PendingIntent for each notification, so the PendingIntent was overwritten everytime with the latest data, and now i am using unique ID everytime and am getting proper data.

**Updated code for Pending Intent**

```
PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, (int) System.currentTimeMillis(), resultIntentMainArticle, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Now coming to my second Requirement **(Requirement-2)**

I wanted to use the heading of that particular notification which user clicks on, in my activity and here i was facing a problem that the data received used to be null everytime, for that i start sending data to my activity using bundle and now i am able to receive the data properly in my activity like this:

**Updated code for sending data to activity**

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("pushClick", "yes");
bundle.putString("pushHead", ""+notTitle);
resultIntentMainArticle.putExtras(bundle);
```

As this is the complete answer to my question, i am marking this answer as an accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

All of your notifications use the same PendingIntent:

```
PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, resultIntentMainArticle, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

This will always update the one and only PendingIntent, because the ID you use is always "0" (see PendingIntent matching for further details). So your PendingIntent will always be updated with the latest resultIntentMainArticle, which contains the heading for the last received push message.
Try to make each of your PendingIntents unique, so they are not overwritten.

Comment: Yeahh right, thanks for pointing out. Can you please help me how can i make each of my PendingIntents unique?
Will using the different ID work in this case? i can use a counter value for this maybe.

Comment: If you always want to show all notifications (never update an existing notification), then just use unique random IDs as you did with mNotificationManager.notify(...). If you wanr to update (change) existing notification, you somehow need to mange the IDs used for both, PendingIntents and Notifications.

Comment: Correct! i have done the changes, let me test it thoroughly.

Comment: the intent value recieved in the activity is always null, what may be the possible reason for that

Comment: @Kunal You meant the intent is null or the intent extras?

Comment: The intent seems to be not null but intent extras are null
I am getting Intent response as 'Intent { cmp=com.mobquid.jiffyfeed/.activities.HomeActivity (has extras) }'